# jQuery: Changing height of a div while changing window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been researching an eventually came up with this:

```
var buttonsHeight = $(".buttonsContainer").height();
var headerHeight = $(".header").height();
var mainWindowHeight = $(window).height();
var sideBarContentHeight;
var sideBarContentHeight =  mainWindowHeight - buttonsHeight - headerHeight - 20;

$('.asideContent').height(sideBarContentHeight);

$( window ).resize(function(){

$('.asideContent').css('height', sideBarContentHeight);

})
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JRUnr/33/

The thing is to **dynamically** change height of sidebar content( column on the right) when screen resolution changes. It kind of works after reshreshing fiddle but when changing window size:  buttons cover text:(
Some help appreciated :)

Comment: Which browsers are you targetting? Have you tried using flexbox and some responsive media queries in your css? Ideally you wouldn't have to do this with javascript at all - the resizing unless you debounce with be a bit jerky and flexboxes are great for this kind of thing. Great article here about flexboxes if you want to read about them... http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/

Comment: Hey, all browsers, ie8 included. I wrote some responsive media queries but I want it to be bullet proof solution..

Comment: But hey, this is a nice link about flexboxes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic is the computation need to happen in the resize handler. In your case you are calculating the height only once(in dom ready) then in the resize event you are assigning the same height again and again

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var buttonsHeight = $(".buttonsContainer").height();
    var headerHeight = $(".header").height();
    var mainWindowHeight = $(window).height();
    var sideBarContentHeight;
    var sideBarContentHeight = mainWindowHeight - buttonsHeight - headerHeight - 20;

    $('.asideContent').height(sideBarContentHeight);

    $('.asideContent').css('height', sideBarContentHeight);

}).resize()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nPnDQ/)

Answer (score 1):

You should compute the height inside the resize handler. Try this,

```
$( window ).resize(function(){
    var buttonsHeight = $(".buttonsContainer").height();
    var headerHeight = $(".header").height();
    var mainWindowHeight = $(window).height();
    var sideBarContentHeight;
    var sideBarContentHeight =  mainWindowHeight - buttonsHeight - headerHeight - 20;
    $('.asideContent').css('height', sideBarContentHeight);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should recalcul all elements

```
function onResize() {
 var buttonsHeight = $(".buttonsContainer").height();
 var headerHeight = $(".header").height();
 var mainWindowHeight = $(window).height();
 var sideBarContentHeight;
 var sideBarContentHeight =  mainWindowHeight - buttonsHeight - headerHeight - 20;
 $('.asideContent').height(sideBarContentHeight);
 $('.asideContent').css('height', sideBarContentHeight);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
 onResize();

 $(window).on('resize', function() {
  onResize();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated your fiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U7Kck/)

```
    var buttonsHeight = $(".buttonsContainer").height();
var headerHeight = $(".header").height();
var mainWindowHeight = $(window).height();
var sideBarContentHeight =  mainWindowHeight - buttonsHeight - headerHeight - 20;

$('.asideContent').height(sideBarContentHeight);

$(window).resize(function(){
     buttonsHeight = $(".buttonsContainer").height();
     headerHeight = $(".header").height();
    mainWindowHeight = $(window).height();
     sideBarContentHeight =  mainWindowHeight - buttonsHeight - headerHeight - 20;
    $('.asideContent').css('height', sideBarContentHeight);

})
```